# 561 returns true on Fermat test

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I found this Fermat's algorithm for testing primes and I found out that it doesn't always return true for Carmichael numbers (such as 561). I tried to find the problem but I can't find anything wrong with the algorithm. What could be the problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class FermatTest {

    private final static Random rand = new Random();

    private static BigInteger getRandomFermatBase(BigInteger n)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            final BigInteger a = new BigInteger (n.bitLength(), rand);
            if (a.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 1 && a.compareTo(n) < 0)
            {
                return a; // 1 <= a < n
            }
        }
    }

    public static String checkPrime(BigInteger n, int maxIterations)
    {
        if (n.equals(BigInteger.ONE))
            return "is composite";

        for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++)
        {
            BigInteger a = getRandomFermatBase(n); //generate random a
            a = a.modPow(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), n); //a^(p-1) mod p

            if (!a.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) // not equals 1
                return "is composite";
        }
        return "is probably prime";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger("561");
        System.out.println(n + " " + checkPrime(n , 20));
        float time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Time: " + (long) time + " nanoseconds");
        time = time / (1000000000);
        System.out.println("Time: " + time + " seconds");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test#Flaw

Answer (score 0):

You identified the problem yourself. There are some numbers, the Carmichael numbers, that are improperly marked prime by the Fermat test for all possible bases. That's just a fact of number theory. You will need a different test to discriminate numbers as prime or composite.